# Increase content area width in TwentyFourteen

Tags: themes, css, theme-twenty-fourteen

In [this website](http://www.kensingtonmn.com/wordpress/) I need to keep the left nav sidebar on the left side of the browser window and get the white content area to extend to the right side of the browser window.

I spent a good two hours trying different CSS settings on div#main and all of its child divs but it was to no avail. Settings such as the div width, floating the divs to the right, etc. Nothing worked.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I strongly disagree with this assessment. This **is** a Wordpress-specific question. I am asking about a specific WP theme and how that particular theme is set up to display. The solution does indeed involve CSS, but it will be CSS code that involves WP-specific knowledge and how WP displays my chosen theme's styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bunch of other things you may want to also do, but in order to make it stretch to the full extent on the right, simply remove the max-width elements from .site and .site-header.

So that's .site {<strike>max-width: 1260px</strike>;} and .site-header {<strike>max-width: 1260px</strike>;}